# What will this synthesize to in DC?

Tags: multidimensional-array, logic, system-verilog, synthesis

What will the be DC synthesis output? I don't have access to DC.  If a=1 and b=1 will both address locations get updated ? Addr1 and addr2 are logic as well and guaranteed not to be equal.

```
logic [3:0][31:0] cache;

always_ff .... begin
.....reset...

if (a) 
  cache[addr1] <= data1;


if (b)
  cache[addr2] <= data2;

end
```

Comment: Don't have access to synthesis tool

Comment: There are free synthesis tools out there, e.g. XST, Vivado synthesis, whatever Intel's FPGAs use, Lattice's tool, etc

Comment: Looking for DC specific results

Comment: This is going to depend on the declaration of `cache` and the target technology you are mapping to.  If `cache` is an array of bits, or can fit into a register file instead of a memory, then no problem.

Comment: Cache is a packed array [3:0][31:0].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will synthesize into a 128-bit register with each input bit fed by a 3-to-1 multiplexor selection a bit from data1, data2, or the previous output bit of the register. The selection logic will be a combinational expression of the addresses, a, and b.